# Tizen no certyficate profile set in the workspace

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have a problem to permit install aplication on my Galay Watch with Tizen Studio. There is always error with no certificate profile found in the workspace.

I have made a Sasmung certyficate and add DUID. The samsusng certyficate extension is instaled. What is going on? I havve tried on two seperate systems Win7 and Win10 separate machines result the same.

http://kamk29.nazwa.pl/fr3sh/postytemp/1.png

http://kamk29.nazwa.pl/fr3sh/postytemp/2.png

Comment: Synchronize your system time with device time and keep awaking your gear. Recreate cert after re-installing Tizen Studio. Give restart of your gear device also.

Comment: I think I have everything in sync, How to check it?

Comment: By sync what I mean is device date and time.